# capture html source code in jquery or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I tried searching this but found no good solution.
My question is I have a HTML form with few text boxes. Once the user enter details and press submit I want to send this same HTML form to administrator email. The problem is I can not get the HTML markup with values. Is there any suggestion.

example

```
<div id="user_form" action="" method="post">
<form onsubmit="return validate_me();">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Name</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="test" id="test"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2">
           <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send"/>
           <input type="hidden" name="html_data" id="html_data"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
</div>
```

So once user click on send button I want to send whole form with values to server then I can send it to admin email. How can I do that.

I tried following

```
<script type="text/javascript>
function validate_me(){
   ("#html_data").val($("#user_form").html());
}
</script>
```

But above send only markup without text box value.
Only above works in IE 9. fail in safari 5.1.7 and FF 23

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciate. Also I tried output buffering but I also did not help to send form element's values.

Comment: 1) Typo in `<from>`. 2) Why?! What do you need the form's HTML for?

Comment: then I can send the html source direct to administrator email without manipulating once again. typo corrected. still same issue in FF and safari. Thanx for helping me out

Comment: Why do you need to send the HTML source to the admin? Because admins love to read their email in HTML? If you think that's easier: it's not hard at all to just take the values themselves and make them into a message. That's a bout 2 lines of PHP code.

Comment: How you are sending it to server. Show your javascript code for that is sending this html to server

Comment: @deceze I have lots of input elements. Every time there is a change in form I have to include that value in email message. Flexibility wise it's not good. That's why I want a simple way to do that.

Comment: @Awais Qarni using post method as I showed in my question.

Comment: `$message = join("\n", array_map(function ($name, $value) { return "$name: $value"; }, array_keys($_POST), $_POST));` - There, I just formatted your message, regardless of what fields it contains.

Comment: @deceze I want to send as html format. Not as a plain text. Using html format It have nicer format. easily readable.

Comment: That wouldn't be much more complicated. Let's put it this way: there's no need whatsoever to keep updating your server side script the more fields you add, if you write it correctly. Capturing client-side form HTML with values is obviously difficult. Also, it allows anyone to send any HTML to your admin's email account, including scripts and embedded content. Does that sounds like a good idea? I'm telling you you're on the wrong track and there's a better way. But whatever, suit yourself.

Comment: @deceze This is basically send lot of forms to emails. So I have to manipulate it in server side every time. That's a pain. security wise this is intranet app.

Comment: Seems like no alternative. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

just submit your form

```
function validate_me(){
 $('#user_form form').submit();
}
```

note: add `action` attribute to your form tag

Comment: form values are submitted correctly. I want to get the html source code.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated code try this 1 and let me know if it not works.

```
<div id="user_form" >
 <form onsubmit="return validate_me();" method="post" action="SOME_ACTION_URL">
 <table>
  <tr>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="test" id="test"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="2">
       <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send"/>
       <input type="hidden" name="html_data" id="html_data"/>
     </td>
  </tr>
```

**EDIT**

```
 <script type="text/javascript>
  // on ready fill the value and then submit it
  jQuery("document").ready(function () {
     jQuery("#html_data").val($("#user_form").html());
  })
  function validate_me(){
   // YOUR code MUST be return 
  return true;
 }
</script>
```

Comment: form values are submitted without problem. But I need to send html source code.

Comment: did you add method post in form and then fetch it on the same page or on the ACTION URL page via print_r($_POST) or ($_REQUEST) it will be there because I set value on ready state so check on firebug if the input value is filled or not

Answer (score 0):

I've just noticed this same problem. What I wanted to do was switch one form with another form yet retain the values the user has entered into the form, such as a message.  I tried outputting the form via console.log and noticed all of the form shows up except the user entered data.

I was attempting to have a second form appear to make sure the user agrees to what they are about to do with a button to go back and make changes. I redisplayed the original form and TADA David copperfield magic, the form is there without any of the content in the inputs. (a text input and textarea)

I am not sure why this happens, I am guessing all I can do is store the user entered data in a namespaced global before trying to save the form data, then redisplay the form and replace the users content one field at a time.

What is the reason for this does anyone know? It must be something about how the inputs work in browsers.

Comment: Sorry for being rude, but could you detail how your answer is actually an answer? By the way, storing data for user approval can be done through get or post variables of the form, and be inserted again as defaut values, or validated by some sort of java script before validation.

Comment: It is not the data I am storing for approval. What I have is a form with two fields, one a text and one a textarea.  The first form is submitted via ajax but only if the user agrees that the data they entered in the text field is what they wanted It is a number. The second form pops up to verify they are who they say they are by having them enter their password. If the password matches the data from the first form is serialized and sent to be processed, if not the password form is redisplayed, with a button to change the data in the first form.

Comment: And my answer is in response to the fact that there appears to be no way to collect the html of a form along with the data of the fields and save or send it as it. And I would have posted my answer as a reply which I tried but it gave me some crap about not have 50 some craps so I couldn't reply so I could only add a comment as an answer.  I had this same question, should i have asked this same basic question again as a form of a repeat?

Comment: It wants 50 reputation. This is as class as you need experience to get a job, but you can't get experience without a job.  But I can make everyone happy and repost my findings as a question that will closely duplicate this one, then listen to people talk about oh this is a duplicate question.

The work and amount of code of having to dig the values out of a serialized form with post or get is a waste. I simply wanted to save the form and redisplay it if there was an error. Which sounds a lot like what the user who asked this question is trying to do.

Comment: I did not get your answer, then, as you write about keeping form data through a step of validation. Concerning the 50 needed reputation: no you can't post if this is duplicate, that would be non-sense; if the question is already asked, maybe someone can answer but maybe not, and posting the same question another time will not help (and will raise the "noise to signal" ratio, which is not what we all want). Anyway, be sure that if this question gets attention from SO people, it will be upvoted and have a better visibility to everyone.